# Get Distinct rows from datagridview1 and pass into datagridview2

Tags: vb.net

I got this code where it select distinct values from datagridview1 and pass the result to datagridview2:

Further Details:
Data from datagridview1

```
Code   Amount
Pro1   100.00
Pro2   300.00
Pro1   100.00
Pro1   100.00
Pro2   300.00
```

The result should be placed in datagridview2 like below;

```
Code   Amount   Count
Pro1   100.00     3
Pro2   300.00     2
```

CODE:

```
Dim dic As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
        Dim cellValue As String = Nothing
        For i As Integer = 0 To dgvSubjectsEnrolled.Rows.Count - 1
            If Not dgvSubjectsEnrolled.Rows(i).IsNewRow Then
                If dgvSubjectsEnrolled(0, i).Value > 0 Then
                    cellValue = dgvSubjectsEnrolled(0, i).Value.ToString()
                    If Not dic.ContainsKey(cellValue) Then
                        dic.Add(cellValue, 1)
                    Else
                        dic(cellValue) += 1
                    End If
                Else
                End If

            End If
        Next

        Dim sb1 As New StringBuilder()
        Dim sb2 As New StringBuilder()
        For Each keyvalue As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In dic
            sb1.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}", keyvalue.Key, keyvalue.Value))
            sb2.AppendLine(String.Format("{1}", keyvalue.Key, keyvalue.Value))
        Next
        Me.dgvsub.Rows.Add(sb1.ToString, sb2.ToString())
```

The code executed successfully but the result is:

```
  Code         Count
Pro1Pro2        32
```

The data was concatenated with the same row. The next value should be at the next row.
Please edit this code.

Comment: Are you looking to compare the count? Or compare each row individually?

Comment: I edited my post. Please review it for further details. thanks @Jacob H

Comment: DistinctValues should be a List of String and you need to replace the ToString at the end with a ToList().  Then you'll have all of the distinct values.

Comment: Can you give me some code on how to pass the result to datagridview2..Please Jus a little bit of codes on how to do it. @N0Alias

Comment: I edited my post.. kindly check what's wrong with my code please..@JacobH and @n()alias

Comment: How did the data get into the DGV?  Where did it come from - a DB?  Using a DataSource it would be simple to count, summarize and group the DATA with a little linq.  UI Controls are how we display data to the user and make horrible collections

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, with a dictionary instead of a list:

```
Private Sub copyDGVs()
    Dim values As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    Dim tmp As String
    Dim arr As String()

    'Make a list of distinct values from DataGridView1, track the count.
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv1.Rows
        tmp = ""
        For j As Integer = 0 To row.Cells.Count - 1
            tmp &= row.Cells(j).Value & "-"
        Next
        If (Not values.ContainsKey(tmp)) Then
            values.Add(tmp, 1)
        Else
            values(tmp) += 1
        End If
    Next

    'Copy that list into DataGridView2
    For Each guy As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In values
        arr = guy.Key.Split("-")
        For q As Integer = 0 To arr.Length - 1
            dgv2.Rows(i).Cells(q + 1).Value = arr(q)
            If (q = arr.Length - 1) Then
                dgv2.Rows(i).Cells(q + 2).Value = guy.Value
            End If
        Next
        i += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

It's not the pretties thing I've ever written, but it should do what you need, unless I goofed the indexes.

PER COMMENTS/EDIT:

I think the problem now is you're appending to your stringbuilders, never resetting them, and not writing inside the loop. Try something like this and see if it works out better:

```
Dim sb1 As StringBuilder()
Dim sb2 As StringBuilder()
For Each keyvalue As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In dic
    sb1 = New StringBuilder()
    sb2 = New StringBuilder()
    sb1.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}", keyvalue.Key, keyvalue.Value))
    sb2.AppendLine(String.Format("{1}", keyvalue.Key, keyvalue.Value))
    Me.dgvsub.Rows.Add(sb1.ToString, sb2.ToString())
Next
```

Comment: i got this error `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`   from this line   `dgvsub.Rows(i).Cells(q + 1).Value = arr(q)`  @user8675309

Comment: Yeah, I'm not surprised, I often mess up my indexes. Start by checking the values of i, q, and q+1 before it fires on that line, and see what it shows for dgvsub.Rows count to make sure it's not less than i, then check that dgvsub.Rows(i) actually has q+1 cells. I go back and forth between C# and VB, and can't remember what's 1-based and what's 0-based anymore. EDIT: Also, it could be that you need arr(q+1) instead of arr(q).

Comment: I edited my post. Kindly please check whats wrong with my code. @user8675309

Comment: Shouldn't you do this in the query itself, so you can manage it at the data layer, rather than deal with it at the presentation layer.